# Calculate value of variable depending on input factors

Tags: jquery, calculator, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the cost of a seat depending on how many are selected, problem is the cost of first seat is different the the rest.

first = 2250
extra seats are charged at 995

What should my syntax and calculation be?

```
//seats variable

var costOfSeats;


//Calculate cost of seats and display cost of seats

$('#range--seats').on("change", function() {

if ($(this).val(1)) {
  costOfSeats == 2250;
} else {
  costOfSeats == costOfSeats + ($(this).val(-1) * 995);// problem here
}

$('.output--seats').val("£" + costOfSeats);
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 3; //number of seats
var sum = 0;
var extraSeat = 995;
var seat = 2250;

if (n != 0) {
    sum = seat + ((n-1) * extraSeat)
}
```

Comment: is it ok to do this for `n` ... `var n = $('#range--seats').val(); //number of seats` ?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: See my other post for this question.

Comment: i've put your code into my codepen and i i think my problem is syntax based, i may have to start a new question http://codepen.io/tands/pen/rjQezx

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKqpRr The fuction that calculates the sum needs to inside the jquery trigger event

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if ($(this).val(1)) {
>   costOfSeats == 2250;
> } else {
>   costOfSeats == costOfSeats + ($(this).val(-1) * 995);// problem here
> }
> ```

You are using `costOfSeats == costOfSeats`, instead of `costOfSeats = costOfSeats` . You are comparing values instead of assigning them